How do I change the colour to look as how a color blind person sees for Deuteranopia and Tritanopia on Davinci Resolve?
I don't know much about colour grading unfortunately so I was wondering if anyone could help me find a way to make a video to show the perspective of a Deuteranopia and Tritanopia colour blindness.
I was specifically wondering if someone could tell me the RGB output on Davinci to get the Deuteranopia and Tritanopia colour blindness for my videos.
I found an example for the colour blindness for protanopia in another post here
Change color to look as how a color blind person sees
This is the Tritanopia colour scale in an EBU bar format
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/fOvJmj6t.png
This is the Deuteranopia colour scale in an EBU bar format
[2]: https://i.sstatic.net/ogJ7JnA4.jpg
Thanks for helping out, it's much appreciated :)

The best way to do this is probably to use a LUT. If you're unfamiliar, you can think of a LUT as a predefined "look" for your video, and they're often used for color correction.
After a quick Google, I found these which  I think would probably work for you. Here's how you can install LUTs in Davinci Resolve. Also, the LUTs at the link I gave you are in .png format, you want them in .cube format. There's plenty of tutorials on how to do this online, here's one to get you started.
